# splitting and resizing files in vim

Tags: vim, resize

I want to do the following:

- open 9 files in vim, (3 x 3 configuration), example files 1,2,...9. each file should take same space to display
- select a file to view, example file 3
- when I select file 3, I want to resize so that this file takes up nearly all the available space, so that i can read it easily
- similarly, I enter a command, so that the files are back to same sized views
- when I select any other file, example 6, then that file should again take up all available space.

The point I'm making is that I know how to select a file (type <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to cycle through files) and if I enter a resize command, example `:res +20` etc, then that file is shown bigger, then I should do `:res -20` to come back to equal views, then tab to another file and repeat the two commands etc, but that is looking clumsy, and I will have to experiment with the number in the res argument. I'm guessing there is a more convenient way to hide all other files, show them back, tab to another file, and repeat the procedure?

Comment: You should get familiar with `CTRL+w` and the `h`,`j`,`k`,`l` as arrows keys, which makes cyclic much more friendly for more than two open files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want that 3x3 grid open you could just `:tabe %` when you're in the window that you want maximized, then just close out of that tab (by typing :q) when you're done with it.  This is really the primary use of tabs, to have different arrangements of windows visible at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

From basic to "one more plugin in my `.vim` folder":

1. `<C-w>_` to maximise current window vertically, `<C-w>|` to do the same horizontally, `<C-w>=` to return to an "equalized" layout. It's all in `:help windows`.
2. `:set winheight=999` and `:set winwidth=999`. Each time you enter a window, it is automatically maximised both horizontally and vertically, minimizing all other windows to 1 column or 1 line.

   I have `set winheight=999` in my `~/.vimrc`, it's very clean. `:set winwidth=999` is horrible.
3. The simple "[Vim-rolodex](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Window_zooming_convenience)" script works well. Be sure to read the rest of the entry.
4. [ZoomWin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508) and [MultiWin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1083) seem to have the same purpose, maybe there are other plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You can tile all buffers into windows by typing:

`:bufdo split`

You can maximize the current window so that only it is visible with: <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

Does that answer your question?

Comment: when i did ctrl+w o then only that is maximized, which is what i want. how do i get out of it, that is, restore the view with multiple files?

Comment: so when i opened 5 files, three vertically and one column with 3 files, and i tabbed into a file and entered ctrl+w o, then that was maximised, then when i did :bufdo split i got to a view with 5 horizontal splits, and the original configuration was lost. is there a way to restore that oroginal configuration?

Comment: @umar - Apologies, I didn't spot the part about "3x3"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
:help bufdo    (this together with split should do what you ask about)
:help only
```

Comment: so once in a particular tab, i type :only so i see only that tab, now how do i restore the original tabs wehn i am done with the file?

Comment: use `:tab ball` to open all buffers in separate tabs